# Exclude Hidden Files From Folder Properties Count

Tags: windows-7

If you right-click and choose properties in Windows Explorer you will get a count of all files and folders.  Included in the count are the thumbs.db files and possibly other system files.

Is there any way to exclude those hidden system files from the count of files?